# How to convert given string to JSON object in jquery / javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a string that looks like the following which I have to convert to a JSON object

```
VL-782597{n=1 c=[3:2.000, 5:1220121144134420.000, 6:4.000, 7:35.000] r=[5:549054495275037.560, 7:5.000]}
```

For `JSON` parse the names must be in quotes which is not there in the string I have.

And the values are assigned as `both = and : instead of : only`

VL-782597 is like row id

How do I format it into `JSON` from `jquery/javascript`. Is this a commonly used format ?

Comment: That's not even a valid JavaScript. How do you get that string?

Comment: How would you like the json to look like? After that the javascript string functions are your friend...

Comment: You will need to parse the string and transform it as appropriate. You need to insert missing quotes, change `=` to `:`, insert missing commas, remove/replace the leading `VL-...`.

Comment: There's no such thing as "JSON object". You probably mean either a JSON string or a JavaScript object.

Comment: No it is not Javascript , it is output of another app, I am stuck using it as a string. Yes ,either of JSON string or javascript object is what i need.